# Get indexes of selected range in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to find the indexes of a highlighted sub string in an `Entry`, so that I can enclose the selection with a function. I assumed that `Entry.selection_range()` would return a `start` and `end` index, but it doesn't.

What I ultimately want to do is this:

```py
everything = Entry.text.get()
start, end = Entry.GET_HIGHLIGHTED_RANGE()
text.set(everything[:start]+'('+everything[end:]+')')
```

Is this possible? Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import TclError

def text_enclose(master,text,operator): 

    try:
        highlighted = master.selection_get()
        everything = text.get()
        enclosed = master.selection_range()
        text.set('NEW'+everything[enclosed[0]:enclosed[-1]])

    except TclError:
        everything = text.get()

        if everything == '':
            pass
        else:
            text.set(operator+'('+everything+')')

root = tk.Tk()

formula = tk.StringVar()

Frame = tk.Frame()
Frame.pack()

TextBox = tk.Entry(Frame)
TextBox.pack()

Button = tk.Button(Frame,text='(+/-)',bg='#e6ffff',command=lambda:text_enclose(TextBox,formula,'-('))
Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `index` method of the `tk.Entry` widget to return the selected positions:

```
start = TextBox.index("sel.first")
end = TextBox.index("sel.last")
```